# Orika mapping is not working

Tags: java, orika

I have defined my mapping for objects HomeContentDTO and SubscriberUpsertDTO

```
public class HomeContentDTO implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1717544153530572470L;

private String fileName;
private String subscriberName;
private String subscriberEmail;
private String subscriberCompanyName;

public String getFileName() {
    return fileName;
}

public void setFileName(String fileName) {
    this.fileName = fileName;
}

public String getSubscriberName() {
    return subscriberName;
}

public void setSubscriberName(String subscriberName) {
    this.subscriberName = subscriberName;
}

public String getSubscriberEmail() {
    return subscriberEmail;
}

public void setSubscriberEmail(String subscriberEmail) {
    this.subscriberEmail = subscriberEmail;
}

public String getSubscriberCompanyName() {
    return subscriberCompanyName;
}

public void setSubscriberCompanyName(String subscriberCompanyName) {
    this.subscriberCompanyName = subscriberCompanyName;
}
}


public class SubscriberUpsertDTO implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6899387128123861532L;
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private String companyName;

    public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getCompanyName() {
    return companyName;
}

public void setCompanyName(String companyName) {
    this.companyName = companyName;
}

public boolean isActive() {
    return active;
}

public void setActive(boolean active) {
    this.active = active;
}
}
```

And following is the mapping config for both objects

```
public class HomeMapperRegister {
    @MapperRegister
    public void register(MapperFactory mapperFactory) {
         mapperFactory.classMap(HomeContentDTO.class, SubscriberUpsertDTO.class)
            .fieldAToB("subscriberName", "name")
            .fieldAToB("subscriberEmail", "email")
            .fieldAToB("subscriberCompanyName", "companyName")
            .register();
    }
}
```

All mapping values from HomeContentDTO not copy to SubscriberUpsertDTO. Do anyone know what's the reason?

```
SubscriberUpsertDTO subscriberUpsertDTO =     mapperFactory.getMapper().map(homeContentDTO, SubscriberUpsertDTO.class);
```

Comment: Can you try fieldBToA ?

Answer (score 2):

```
class HomeMapperRegister extends ConfigurableMapper {

    @Override
    public void configure(MapperFactory mapperFactory) {
        mapperFactory.classMap(HomeContentDTO.class, SubscriberUpsertDTO.class)
                .fieldAToB("subscriberName", "name")
                .fieldAToB("subscriberEmail", "email")
                .fieldAToB("subscriberCompanyName", "companyName")
                .register();
    }
}
```

`extends` from `ConfigurableMapper` and `Override` `configure` function to map.

Comment: Sorry I didn't post all my code. I have actually generated the getter and setter functions for both objects. I will update my code above.